# Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules()

Tags: php, apache

i am able to run in local host but in host server getting this  error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules() in
>   /home/jamboree/public_html/installer_html/step1.php on line 148

my code is:
**step1.php**

```
$isEnabled = in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules());
                                                if ($isEnabled) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <span class="label label-success">
                                                        <?php
                                                        echo "install";
                                                        ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <?php
                                                } else {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <span class="label label-warning">
                                                        <?php
                                                        echo "not install";
                                                        ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <?php
                                                }




                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Server is running PHP as FPM or some kind of (f)CGI . It might even be a different web server like nginx. Anyway it doesn't run in apache's context and thus the apache_* functions aren't available.

I would think about making the installation of your software depend on whether or not you can determine availability of rewrite rules. First of all you can't even make sure in Apache and secondly you might have a different web server with a different configuration format (like nginx).

Comment: I am working on a pre install script to see if rewrite rule is enabled on web server. What is the best way to do this when i don't know which web server is being used, script should run in case of any web server ideally

Comment: Normally I'd say tell the user that rewrite is available and tell them how to enable it in different web servers. Don't make your code depend on it. You could also try to determine which configuration format works by trying out different formats in a subdirectory and calling that from within your install script.